# Convert python with numpy to c++ with opencv

Tags: python, c++, numpy, opencv

I'm working on some optimazation and want to convert some parts from python to c++

Is it possible to convert this code to c++ with `opencv`?

The python code uses `numpy`

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

pil_img = Image.open(input_filename)
img = np.array(pil_img)
pixels = img.reshape((-1, 3))

num_pixels = pixels.shape[0]
num_samples = int(num_pixels*5)

idx = np.arange(num_pixels)
np.random.shuffle(idx)

samples = pixels[idx[:num_samples]]
```

## update

```
std::vector<uchar> sample_pixels(const cv::Mat& m, int sample_percent=5){
    assert(m.isContinuous());
    
    const auto* input = m.ptr<uchar>();
    
    int
        num_pixels      = m.total(),
        num_samples     = num_pixels * sample_percent;
    
    std::cout
        << "num pixels:  " << num_pixels << '\n'
        << "num samples: " << num_samples << '\n';
    
    std::vector<uchar> samples(num_samples);
    
    //  Fills idx with sequentially increasing values
    std::vector<int> idx(num_pixels);
    std::iota(idx.begin(), idx.end(), 0);
    
    //  Shuffle idx
    std::mt19937 engine(0);
    std::shuffle(idx.begin(), idx.end(), engine);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < num_samples; i++){
        //samples[i] = input[idx[i]];
    }
    
    //auto output_mat = cv::Mat(samples, false);
    //cv::imwrite("enhance-samples.png", output_mat);
    
    return samples;
}
```

Comment: Isn't Numpy basically BLAS?

Comment: yes it's possible. You may not get any performance improvement, though.

Comment: `opencv` can be used with `python` as well as its native c++.  So a first step might be to replace the PIL use with `opencv`.  There are plenty of SO examples using `opencv`.  Any further use of c++ depends on your familiarity with the language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the equivalent code in C++11. This should be several times faster than your python code.

```cpp
#include <random>
#include <numeric>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

void shuffling(const std::string &input_filename, const std::string &output_filename) {

    // ========== UPDATE ==========
    const cv::Mat plain_input_mat = cv::imread(input_filename, -1);
    // Equivalent to img.reshape((-1, 3))
    const cv::Mat input_mat = plain_input_mat.reshape(3);
    // ============================

    // By doing this, you can access the pixels without any extra checks.
    assert(input_mat.isContinuous());
    const auto *input = input_mat.ptr<cv::Vec3b>();

    const auto num_samples = input_mat.total();
    std::vector<cv::Vec3b> output(num_samples);

    std::vector<int> idx(input_mat.total());
    std::iota(idx.begin(), idx.end(), 0);  // Equivalent to arange.

    // Note: numpy uses PCG64 which does not exist in the std library.
    std::mt19937 engine(0);
    std::shuffle(idx.begin(), idx.end(), engine);

    for (int i = 0; i < num_samples; i++) {
        output[i] = input[idx[i]];
    }

    // Save as an image if necessary.
    auto output_mat = cv::Mat(output, false);
    cv::imwrite(output_filename, output_mat);
}
```

There are a couple of additional notes.

Note1: Due to the difference in the shuffle algorithm between python and std, the results are not exactly the same.

Note2: With your code, `num_samples` cannot be larger than the number of pixels in the input image, which seems to be a bug. Please check the length of the `samples`.

Note3: In both implementations, the most expensive part is `shuffle`. 60% for python and more than 80% for C++ is spent here. If you want to optimize further, this is definitely where you should exploit.

Comment: I'm looking at your code. What does `input_mat.ptr<cv::Vec3b>();` do? Will it convert the matrix to a pointer and is `<cv::Vec3b>` some kind of casting? Will it cast the matrix to `CV_8UC1`?

Comment: Ok, after some research it looks like `cv::Vec3b` is 3 channel :) Have made an update to the question with some changes. Have changed `cv::Vec3b` to `uchar` because the input is 1 channel grayscale. But have an issue with the code. If `samples[i] = input[idx[i]];` is uncommented the code returns an error

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. `input_mat.ptr<cv::Vec3b>()` casts the pointer to CV_8UC3 (not a conversion). This does not have to match the format of the input image, but rather how you want to treat it. In your python code, you are reshaping the image leaving 3 channels, this means that 3 elements will be copied in a single assignment. If you want this behavior, leave it as `Vec3b`. What you should do instead is to reshape the input in the same way as your python code. See my update.

Comment: Two things to note: First, This reshaping is only valid if the number of pixels in the input is a multiple of 3 (as in python code). Second, you define `num_samples` as `num_pixels * sample_percent`, but that is 5 times of `num_pixels`, not 5 percent. This causes out-of-indexing (also as in python code, so you should debug it first).

Comment: Sorry it had to be `0.05` (5%).. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: but is it necessary to do `plain_input_mat.reshape(3);` when you do `input_mat.ptr<cv::Vec3b>()` ??

Comment: `mat.reshape(3)` only changes the shape information so that `mat.total()` returns the correct value. So you can actually remove `mat.reshape(3)` and adjust these values manually, like `mat.total() / 3`. But I think `mat.reshape(3)` would be much more straightforward.